# Generate two random strings with dash in between

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am wondering how to make a code in python 3.4.3 that can generate two 3 character long strings. One Digits 0 - 9, and the other capital letters of the alphabet. There also has to be a dash between them.

Examples:

```
MUS-875

KLE-443

AMI-989
```

This is what I have

```
from random import randint

print(randint(2,9))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try picking a random string of letters, then a random string of digits, then joining them with a hyphen:

```
import string, random
def pick(num):
    for j in range(num):
        print("".join([random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(3)])+"-"+"".join([random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(3)]))
```

As such:

```
>>> pick(5)
OSD-711
KRH-340
MDE-271
ZJF-921
LUX-920
>>> pick(0)
>>> pick(3)
SFT-252
XSL-209
MAF-579
```

Comment: It works! How would I make it print 5 or so of these strings automaticly when you run the module, and once more, when you type pick()

Comment: @user2368535, no problem, would you mind upvoting my answer if it helped you? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using `random.choice` and `.format`, you could do something like this:

```
>>>import random, string
>>>"{0}-{1}".format(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for x in range(3)),
                           ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for x in range(3)))
```

**Outputs:**

```
'FLL-242'
```